# Expected value of the number of days where k people share their birthdays

Tags: probability, expected-value, birthday

I am trying to find the expected value of the number of days where exactly $k$ people have a birthday in a  class  which consists of $60$ independently chosen people.

For $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$

I am confused if the answer here is similar to the answer to this  [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/birthday-problem-expected-number-of-collisions%20), as here we need the expected value of the days not people?

And does the term "independently chosen" imply that I also need to apply a probability of choosing a certain person from the 60 ppl or is it just an indication to get the product of the events?

Any hints greatly appreciated

Comment: [A related question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365713/birthday-problem-which-solution-for-expected-value-of-collisions-is-correct) gives three similarly worded questions with different answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usual assumptions (each person's birthday independently and uniformly distributed over $365$ days) the probability that exactly $k$ out of $60$ people share $1$ January as a birthday is binomial: ${60 \choose k}\frac{364^{60-k}}{365^{60}}$, and similarly for each of the $365$ days you might consider

So the expected number of days that have exactly $k$ people sharing that day as a birthday is   $${60 \choose k}\frac{364^{60-k}}{365^{59}}$$

For small values of $k$ this gives the following (rounded) expectations

```
k     0       1       2        3         4           5            6
E  309.6022 51.03333 4.135943 0.2196746 0.008599899 0.0002646123 0.000006663771
```

and these add up to about $365$ as you might expect; unrounded and taking $k$ from $0$ through to $60$, the sum would be exactly $365$